# Angularjs ng-messages input[time]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-moment

i"m tring to display error with ng-message when first value input time inferior value input second 
any
any idea please ?

**html**

```
<input type="time" ng-model="mytime.morning"/>
```

**controller**

```
$scope.mytime={};
$scope.mytime.morning=moment("06:00", ["h:mm"]).toDate();
```

Comment: What does this mean `when first value input time inferior value input second` ? It is not clear.

Comment: @DavidR it's men when first input < second input

Answer (score 0):

In order to compare two values you will need to have 2 values. Once you enter a new time the one the in initialized is gone, so i suggest making another variable to hold the other time...

Then you will have 2 values to compare against each other.

Comment: Can u make demo please ?